# Cgroup fork subsystem

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, fork, limit, cgroups

My OS:

```
logioniz@Mozgolom:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.04"
```

Cgroups doesn't contain fork subsystem:

```
logioniz@Mozgolom:~$ grep -E -i  "^subsys" /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-34/include/linux/cgroup_subsys.h
SUBSYS(cpuset)
SUBSYS(debug)
SUBSYS(cpu_cgroup)
SUBSYS(cpuacct)
SUBSYS(mem_cgroup)
SUBSYS(devices)
SUBSYS(freezer)
SUBSYS(net_cls)
SUBSYS(blkio)
SUBSYS(perf)
SUBSYS(net_prio)
SUBSYS(hugetlb)
```

But i found this patch http://lwn.net/Articles/465574/.
I do not know if this patch is applied, but I would like to have the opportunity to limit the number of processes.
How can I add these or similar functionality using only cgroup?